# boto3 dynamodb batch_writer how to perform rollback

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, rollback

I'm using boto3 to access AWS dynamodb table and batch write to it, here is the sample code:

```py
with table.batch_writer() as batch:
    try:
        for i in range(10):
            id = uuid.uuid4().hex

            # A function which perform a job and finish with write to the table
            # If the job fails, the function will raise an exception
            write_to_table(batch, id)
    except:
        # Perform a rollback
        print("{} failed".format(id))
```

Is it possible to perform a rollback to the entire batch using the **BatchWriteItem**? (in the except block for instance).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but I'm not sure it's a good one:

```py
batch = table.batch_writer()
try:
    for i in range(10):
        id = uuid.uuid4().hex
        write_to_table(batch, id)

    batch._flush()
except:
    print("passive rollback")
```